# Names for database tables like t1,t2,t3 etc

Tags: java, sql, database-design, mybatis

We have the following situation - we have framework with which different developers can work and who don't know about other developers. And we have a customer who can take extensions (ebj osgi bundles and sql scripts) from different developers and add them to one database.

So as there are different developers there can be name conflicts (table, index, foreign keys). We would like to implement java like name - for example: comOrganizationFooTable however the maximum length of table name and columns is 30 characters. Besides it is CRUD application and there are tons of joins with tables that can be from different developers. And the last - we use mybatis with xml mappers.

Taking all this into consideration I think about the following solution. Customer adds new tables to database via special program that reads all long database names, replaces them to tN, creates tables tN,tM... and in special tables saves the links (t2 -> table original name). After that when ejb osgi bundle starts program replaces original names in xml mapper with tX and loads this updated xml mapper to mybatis configuration.

The most important thing is that long unique original names exist both in both sections of xml mapper: in mapper section and sql code section. **It's very important when we join different tables and want to use mapper sections from different xml mappers.**

Example:

```
<resultMap id="readItemsRM" type="com.mycompany.product.SomeDTO">
        <id property="id" column="%comMyCompanyProductSomeTable.id"/>
        <result property="name" column="%comMyCompanyProductSomeTable.name"/>
</resultMap>

 <sql id="mainSelect">
   SELECT 
     %comMyCompanyProductSomeTable.id,
     %comMyCompanyProductSomeTable.name
   FROM
     %comMyCompanyProductSomeTable
 </sql>
```

So, after dynamic changes all `%comMyCompanyProductSomeTable` becomes for example `t29`.

Following this methos we don't need to use any `AS`. All references across databases are unique and we don't exceed the maximum table and column name limits.

**The question** - how do you think, is it good or bad solution and what are other solutions of such problem?

Comment: Why can't you just create a separate database per-customer?

Comment: @Explosion Pills Because even the customer takes extenstions from 5 developers he will have 5 dabatase - which necessary to backup and make settings for java-ee servers. And besides this case we forget about foreign keys and data integrity.

Comment: @Explosion Pills Besides - developers don't know about customer. Every developer knows only about its own extension and doesn't care about anything else.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea - each customer should have either their own database, their own schema, or some combination of the two (ideal).  With how you've described it, you can neither enforce security easily (if at all) nor will it be maintainable, and as you hint, can lead to table name conflicts, among other problems.

Comment: @Siyual Thank you for your comment. However, I don't understand you. What I suggest is all about ONLY ONE DATABASE! But this single database has tables from different developers.

Comment: @iJava If it must be in only one database, then each developer should have their own `Schema`, with security restrictions on their account to only have access to that particular schema.

Comment: @Siyual I understand what you are talking about. The developers don't have access to database. They only give sql scripts to customer and ejb bundles. It's up to customer to install them or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use **namespaces**. That's what namespaces are for. In database-land, a namespace is called a **schema**. MySQL decided to be weird and call their schemas 'databases'

Normal db server:

```
Database Cluster
   Databases
     Schemas
       Tables, etc
```

MySQL db server:

```
Database Cluster
     Schemas (called 'databases')
       Tables, etc
```

Force developerX to use `developerX` schema. If he makes a table `kittens`, it must be called `developerX.kittens`

Yes, you can have foreign keys between schemas. Use the fully qualified name in your foreign key: `schema_name.table_name`.

Anyways, if you don't want to do that, then come up with a short code prefix for your developer companies, such as "x3" for "Company 12", and force them to prefix table names with their prefix code, such as `x3_kittens`. This is no less work than schemas, and is hackish.

Comment: Do I understand you right - you suggest to have multiple schemas/databases? Is schema=database?

Comment: One database, multiple schemas in the database. Which DB are you using?

Comment: I use mysql. Can you explain? I always thought that database -> tables. But as far as I understand you, you suggets database -> schema - >tables?

Comment: A mysql database server only hosts one *real* database. This database has many schemas. But mysql are jerks and call the schemas "databases". If you look at postgres, you'd see multiple databases with multiple schemas.

Comment: Ok. So as I understand you for mysql database -> table = schema -> table. It's not important how we call database o schema. If we create schema/database for every developer than it's not only difficult to administrate but more important that we loose data integrity as there can no be foreign keys between two databases /schemas.

Comment: @IJava that is not true. You can have foreign keys between schemas. Just use schemaname.tablename .

Comment: I didn't know. Is it a good practice? What is better - to have distinct schemas and fk between them or have prefix (t1) in table names?

Comment: Of course it's good practice, that's why I recommended it to you ;)

Comment: You say that normal db have .... What do you mean normal? Oracle, MSSQL, Postgresql, Derby, H2?

Comment: By "normal" I mean "everyone other than MySQL"

Comment: So do all rdbms I listed have it?

Comment: Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres do multi databases with schemas, I'm not sure about Derby or H2, but probably.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I always worked only with mysql and didn't know about schemas.